# Movie about aliens vs humans on a total war (1990s)

Tags: identify-this-movie

I don't remember the exact year but it should late 90s, we watched our first DVD with our family. I was a child at that time so I don't remember lots of details. But I have few of them. I hope you can help me on finding the name of the movie.

- It was an US based movie
- I remember that aliens(they were big) and humans (soldiers only) were in a total war. Soldiers was attacking them with machine guns.
- I remember a scene in which soldiers were throwing a party at their camp, they were all drunk and aliens did a surprise attack to the camp.
- I remember a scene a male soldier cuts the alien's body with knife and put a hand grenade inside it.

These are the only memories that I have. I hope we can find this movie because it has a special place in my life.

Comment: give more info regarding the movie... any big stars ... or location.... language..... and sort of graphics ... u seen

Comment: r u sure they are aliens .....?   because u said **they were all drunk and aliens did a surprise attack to the camp.**

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification.What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: [**Identify-This-X Questions**](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: it was an US based movie. Language was english and soldiers were american. I don't remember any big star

Comment: @JayGatsby Are you the original poster?

Comment: @AJ [he explained below](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72185/movie-about-aliens-vs-humans-on-a-total-war-1990s#comment116853_72187), he accidentally posted this from a new acct.

Comment: @Riker He can always merge the accounts.

Answer (score 38):

I think this might be *[Starship Troopers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120201/)*.

Massive aliens and only human soldiers.

And there is a scene where a trooper jumps onto the back of an alien and 'shoots' a hole into it and drops a grenade in the hole:

Maybe?

Comment: My first thought too - It's been a while, so my memory might be fuzzy, but there was a scene where they are all celebrating and they get attacked. There's also the scene you mention where the guy shoots a hole in the alien and throws a grenade in there.

I do not think there were any knife scenes though (with regard to aliens, there are some human/human knife scenes).

Comment: Near the end Zander slices the brain bug with his knife, perhaps that's the scene?

Comment: yes that's correct movie! But I'm so sorry I can't accept the answer since I accidently post the question with an anonymous account

Comment: Yep, definitely ST - however, the party goes through fine.  They aren't attacked in the middle of it, but they do have to break camp sooner than expected.

Comment: It's Carmen who cuts the brain bug in the end, not Zander.

Comment: @JayGatsby http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts